# Angular: immediately return from ngClick function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a dropdown menu on my page, which is really just an unordered list, where each menu item looks like:

```
<li ng-click='doCalc(5)'>Five</li>
```

Now, the function that `doCalc` calls might take a little while:

```
function doCalc(num) {
  factorial(num);
}
```

This means that the menu stays on the screen while `factorial` runs.  What I'd like is for `doCalc` to return immediately, not waiting for `factorial` to finish running.

I know how to do this with a no-delay setTimeout, and with a promise.  **But what's the Angular Way to do this**? Searching for "angular promise" yields a sea of results about HTTP requests, when here I am just doing a humble calculation.

Comment: I my opinion you should stick with `setTimeout`, in angular way of using `$timeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise can be created with either the `$q` service or the `$timeout` service.

```
function doCalc(num) {
    return $q.when(factorial(num));
};
```

### Or

```
function doCalc(num) {
    return $timeout(function() {return factorial(num)}, 0);
};
```

---

> Is there a preference for one or the other? If I have lots of async requests also going on in the page, will when be blocked?

Both the `$q` service  and the `$timeout` service use the `$q` queue (and below that `setTimeout`). Be aware that both the browser queue and the Angular `$q` queue operate on a single thread. That means that once the `factorial` function starts, it runs to completion. If you are concerned about the `factorial` service causing problems with other asychronous operations, then that function needs to be broken up with multiple calls to `$q.when` or `$timeout` (which both ultimately call `setTimeout`).

Comment: Is there a preference for one or the other? If I have lots of async requests also going on in the page, will when be blocked?

Comment: why to return promise via `ng-click` function. `ng-click` isn't expecting for any value..

Comment: Returning things to functions makes them more versatile. The OP may decide to use the function in some other context.

Comment: Regarding your edit: so I guess going with $q.when is never worse than going with $timeout? I'm only asking because the `when` syntax is so much cleaner IMO.

Comment: @SteveD In this case, I would go with `$q.when`. Unless $timeout is already injected. It really doesn't matter much. It's good to know that either way works.